# Is it possible to use complex boolean logic in a CQL query?

Tags: cassandra, cql

In cassandra , for a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE test.TestTable3 (
   PK1 int,
   PK2 int,
   CK3 int,
   CK4 int,
   CK5 text,
   CK6 int,
   CK7 int,
   Dump text,
   PRIMARY KEY ((PK1,PK2,CK3),CK4,CK5,CK6,CK7)
);
```

How to do query something like ie using or with partial or

```
Select * from testtable3 where Pk1=1 and Pk2=2 and Ck3 =2 and Ck4 =4 and (( CK=5 ="ABC" 
and  CK6=1) or ( CK=5 ="BBC" and CK6=1))
```

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let me just say that Cassandra does not support complex, ad-hoc queries.  The Cassandra Query Language (CQL) is a *subset* (not an implementation) of SQL.  Therefore, you cannot do everything in CQL that may work in SQL.

Secondly, CQL does not support the `OR` operator.  However, you can use the `IN` operator in some cases.  Essentially, `IN` only works on the partitioning key.  And only on the last partitioning key, if using a composite partitioning key (as you are).  Be warned though, that as Cassandra is designed to serve reads on specific, primary key queries, it is not recommended to rely on the use of `IN`.  See [SELECT: When *not* to use IN](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) for more information.

Third, unlike a relational database, in Cassandra it is good practice to denormalize/replicate your data while building it into multiple tables to support each desired query.  With that in-mind, you could create a query table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable4 (
   PK1 int,
   PK2 int,
   CK3 int,
   CK4 int,
   CK5 text,
   CK6 int,
   CK7 int,
   Dump text,
   PRIMARY KEY ((PK1,PK2,CK3,CK4,CK6,CK5),CK7)
);
```

Note how I have extended the partition key, and changed the order of `CK5` and `CK6`.  Given this table structure, this query works:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM testtable4 WHERE pk1=1 AND pk2=2 AND ck3=3
              ... AND ck4=4 AND ck6=1 AND ck5 IN ('ABC','BBC');

 pk1 | pk2 | ck3 | ck4 | ck6 | ck5 | ck7 | dump
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------
   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   1 | ABC |   7 | row ABC
   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   1 | BBC |   7 | row BBC

(2 rows)
```

Note: I used this structure to show you how Cassandra query-based-modeling works.  I have no idea if this would work with your overall application or data, so take that for what it's worth.